# Entity Framework Core: relation many to one with nullable foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two tables in my database :

```
public class PARENT
{
    public string ID_PARENT { get; set; }    
    public int? ID_PARENT_BIS { get; set; }    

    public List<CHILD> CHILDREN { get; set; } 
}
```

This table has a primary key : `ID_PARENT`.

The `ID_PARENT_BIS` is used into several relationships.

```
public class CHILD
{
    [Required]
    public string PID_CHILD { get; set; } 

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? ID_PARENT_BIS { get; set; } 

    [Required]
    public string ID_EXTCHILD { get; set; } 
}
```

Between both, there are a relationships many to one. Here is the mapping :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PARENT>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.ID_PARENT);

            entity.HasMany(a => a.CHILDREN)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.ID_PARENT_BIS)
                .HasPrincipalKey(i => i.ID_PARENT_BIS);
        });
```

The mapping is correct but when I want to retrieve all elements of `PARENT`, I get the following error :

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. InvalidCastException: La colonne contient des données NULL (Column contain null data)

My relation need to be configured to work with `ID_PARENT_BIS`, not `ID_PARENT`. Because `ID_PARENT_BIS` could be null in database. This is a prerequisites of the project.

So is it really possible to do that with Entity Framework Core?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is your code yelling? You don't have to use UPPERCASE for entities even if your database looks like that

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I know, but it's not me who make project rules

Comment: EF Core does not support nullable [alternate keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys). In your case, the problem is `ID_PARENT_BIS` in `PARENT`  (in `CHILD` it is FK, hence ok).

Comment: @IvanStoev There is a way to do a many to one relationships, with a nullable attribute in parent ? Other than with a alternate keys ?

Comment: Negative. Parent field **must** be primary or alternate (unique) key and **must not** be nullable.